# Migrating CDI/EJB annotations to Spring annotations

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, ejb, cdi

I'm trying to replace my CDI/EJB annotations with Spring ones. But I'm struggeling how to do it right.

This is what I have in CDI/EJB:

```
@Stateless
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
class Service {
    @Inject
    EntityManager em;
}


@Named
@RequestScoped
class Facade {
    @Inject
    Service service;
}
```

Now I would do the following:

```
@Stateless
@Transactional
@Repository
class Service {
    @Inject
    EntityManager em;   
}
```

What about the stateless? What is the aquivalent in spring?
Obvious I cannot just remove this annotation, bc then I'm getting these exception:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /input.xhtml @15,30 registerButtonAction="#{facade.createNew()}": The class 'Facade$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy' does not have the property ...
```

Further:

```
@Named
@Service
class Facade {
    @Autowired
    Service service;
}
```

Do I have to simply replace all `@Inject` annotations with `@Autowired`?
Is there something in Spring that takes care of EL naming, so that I can remove the `@Named`?

Do I have to annotate my JPA entities too?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Not trying to start a flame war, just curious.

Comment: bc spring annotations make things quite easy. eg aspects, can catch exceptions on all @Component annotated classes.

Comment: EE6 / EJb 3.1 / CDI also offers such aspect functionality with annotations, interceptors etc. For that case I don't see the value in the effort to switch but thats just me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Stateless` and `Stateful` Beans are `EJB` concepts, but `Spring` offers similar services through Service Beans. Put the `@Service` annotation in your Business Logic classes, and if you want your beans to be "Stateless" or "Stateful" just configure your bean scope (like `Request` or `Session`).

`Spring` also has a built-in transaction management API, so your Transaction annotations may need to be changed.

Finally, `Spring` is compatible with many persistence frameworks including `JPA`. IF you want to keep `JPA` it is OK, and feel free to change it for another technology if you desire (maybe `Hibernate`, or `MyBatis`)

Answer (score 1):

The stateless and stateful concepts are EJB; Spring doesn't have such a notion.  Spring uses POJOs, without any support for stateful beans.  You're on your own there.

Spring uses `javax.annotation.Resource` annotation; I'd prefer that to `@Autowired`.

Answer (score 1):

Spring supports `@Inject` and `@Named` directly.  No need to use `@Autowired` and `@Component` (Spring's equivalents) if you don't want to.  No need to bring in `@Resource` either.

```
// This is a singleton by default, which is OK since you previously
// had it marked as stateless
@Named
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
class Service {
    @PersistenceContext   // Use JPA's usual annotation
    EntityManager em;
}

// You may not still need this, but if you do ...
@Named
@Scope("request")
class Facade {
    @Inject
    Service service;
}
```